# Rails trying to join a table. Column not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am trying to return a json response with a game and a game_image from a search result.

I have the following code:

**Controller:**

```
  def search
    @games = Game.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC").joins(:game_image).where( game_image: { primary: true })
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => {:message => "Success", :results => @games}}
    end
  end
```

the search function works and is just a simple `LIKE` query in sql. Now I am trying to join the game_image table which should only pick the primary image.

**Models:**

```
class GameImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :game_id, :image, :primary , :title
  belongs_to :game
  mount_uploader :image, GameImageUploader
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :activated, :description, :metascore, :metascore_url, :name, :pegi_rating, :youtube_url, :release_date , :game_link_attributes , :game_platform_attributes , :edition_attributes , :game_edition_attributes, :game_image_attributes
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :game_link
  has_many :shop , through: :game_link
  has_many :game_platform
  has_many :game_genre
  has_many :game_edition
  has_many :edition , through: :game_edition
  has_many :game_image

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_image, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_link, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_platform, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :edition, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_edition, allow_destroy: true

  def self.search(query)
    where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
  end
end
```

**db migrate file for game_image:**

```
class CreateGameImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :game_images do |t|
      t.integer :game_id
      t.string :image
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :primary

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Problem:**

Saying no such column altough this column exists. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: game_image.primary: SELECT "games".* FROM "games" INNER JOIN "game_images" ON "game_images"."game_id" = "games"."id" WHERE "game_image"."primary" = 't' AND (name like '%di%') ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Take a look at your relations.  `Game has_many  game_images` (You see the plural? at game_images). Fix that in  your model and then your query should be: `Game.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC").joins(:game_images).where( game_images: { primary: true })` (again the plural form for game_images)

Comment: Hello, I just tried this. But I usually always use the singular. Using the plural causes `No association found for name game_image. Has it been defined yet?`

Comment: Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association and you will see that you should use plural version. From the manual: `The name of the other model is pluralized when declaring a has_many association.` Soo, in game.rb use: `has_many :game_images` and  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_images, allow_destroy: true` and rewrite your query as in the first comment.

Comment: Thanks I did this, but now I get `Association named 'game_image' was not found on Game; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Did you update your `.join(:game_images)` to plural as well?

Comment: OK. changed it, but now it is still not joining the table `game_image`.

Comment: What happens now? Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: No error. But its not showing the images `results: [{activated: false, created_at: "2015-05-23T10:30:16Z", description: "", id: 1, metascore: null,…}]
0: {activated: false, created_at: "2015-05-23T10:30:16Z", description: "", id: 1, metascore: null,…}
activated: false
created_at: "2015-05-23T10:30:16Z"
description: ""
id: 1
metascore: null
metascore_url: ""
name: "Diablo 3"
pegi_rating: null
release_date: null
updated_at: "2015-05-23T10:30:16Z"
youtube_url: `  JSON Response in Chrome Network